# Javascript listens for events only on the last node specified

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

So I am working on a simple gui. The problem is that ONLY the last `textarea` seems be affected by the script. All the previous do not react at all. (check the screenshot)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){

// Interactive textareas
var txta = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var i = 0; i < txta.length; i++){
    var earse = txta[i].value;
    console.log(earse); // debugging
    txta[i].addEventListener('focus', function(e){
        if (e.target.value === earse) {
            e.target.value = "";
            e.target.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
                if (e.target.value === "") {
                    e.target.value = earse;
                }
            }, false);
        }
    }, false);
    console.log(txta[i]); // debugging
};

}, false);
```

Screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwa2v.jpg): [image: screenshot]

Html is just few simple `textarea`'s with a value all specified in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure inside function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){

// Interactive textareas
var txta = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var i = 0; i < txta.length; i++){
    var earse = txta[i].value;
    console.log(earse); // debugging
    (function(earse){
            txta[i].addEventListener('focus', function(e){
                    if (e.target.value === earse) {
                            e.target.value = "";
                            e.target.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
                                    if (e.target.value === "") {
                                            e.target.value = earse;
                                    }
                            }, false);
                    }
            }, false);
        })(earse);
    console.log(txta[i]); // debugging
};

}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WjV8n/

For comment: You need closure varible **earse** inside loop. Because every step you change this varible.

Comment: We really need a canonical question to link to for these questions. They come up dozens of times a day.

Comment: I still don't understand why do I need to "closure varible earse inside loop". It should just simply work because the variable should be overwritten each time.

Comment: @Johnny Well, `earse === txta[txta.length]` at the time the event handler is execueted. Here in Mihail's code `earse` is passed as an argument to an anonymous function. The `for` loop can't change this argument (it's local in the anonymous function), and you can preserve a value of `earse` as it was at the iterate time in your event handler.

Comment: I know he is passing the earse to the anonymous function. What I don't understand is why is it not working without it. What's the difference in interpreting this code by javascript. In mine example it just should go like this: earse is this, add event listeners - 3 times.

Comment: Johnny: beacause after for-loop, earse === (value of last textarea). In the anonymous function with argument, each textarea have own earse varible.

Comment: That's true but by that time all `eventListeners` should be set up? (Otherwise it will run `for` 3 times and then start adding `eventListener`'s?)

Comment: Johnny: Yes, but without anonymous function, in onfocus event you will compare value with earse from last step of for-loop.