# Javascript only last event listener works

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

It's very difficult for me to show you my code, as it's all over the place, but what I'm trying to do is this:

I am injecting html code into the DOM in a function buy using `.innerHTML`, I wish to add a click event to an icon that is being injected in this step, as at this moment in time I know its id. So after I've injected it I write:

`document.getElementById(product.id+"x").addEventListener("click", removeItem);`

`product.id` is created above and this element is a 'X' button, that when clicked will be removed from the screen.

The trouble is, this code is run many times as there are many items to be displayed on the screen. And when finished, only the last even made fires when the 'X' button is pressed.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I am unable to use jquery in this project.

Here is my code:

```
function createHTML(targetID, product) {
    var target = document.getElementById(targetID);
    total = (parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(product.price)).toFixed(2);;
    target.innerHTML += '<article class="item" id="'+product.id+'"><img class="item_img" src="../'+product.image+'" width=100 height=100><h1 class="item_name">'+product.name+'</h1><p class="item_description">'+product.desc+'</p><h1 class="item_quantity">Quantity: '+product.quantity+'</h1><h1 class="item_price">&pound;'+product.price+'</h1><i id="'+product.id+'x" class="fa fa-times"></i></article>';

    document.getElementById(product.id+"x").addEventListener("click", removeItem, true);
}
```

Comment: javascript `closure` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892367/javascript-listens-for-events-only-on-the-last-node-specified?rq=1

Comment: I was thinking I needed some kind of wrapper function to make it work, but at the moment I am not quite sure how it would work, could you explain a bit more please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you're adding new elements to a container by overwriting the `innerHTML` or appending to it using `+=`. This is your problem. When you overwrite the `innerHTML` or append to it, you are destroying and recreating all elements within it and this causes them to lose any bound event handlers (ie your click handler).

**[This fiddle reproduces your problem. Only the last button has a click handler.](http://jsfiddle.net/3cD4G/)**

The solution is to build DOM elements using `document.createElement()` and use `appendChild()` or similar to append them, instead of creating/appending raw HTML. This way, your previous elements event handlers will remain intact.

**[This Fiddle uses DOM nodes instead of raw HTML and all buttons have a click handler.](http://jsfiddle.net/KfYh6/)**

Example fix:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var elem;

function clicky(){
    alert("clicked");   
}

for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
    elem = document.createElement('button');
    elem.id = "btn_" + i;
    elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click'));
    elem.addEventListener("click", clicky);
    container.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain, they aren't being overwritten as I am using ```+=``` to append to the end of the ```innerHTML```

Comment: They are still being overwritten, `+=` doesn't make a difference. The browser still destroys everything within and recreates.

Comment: @benharris have a look at my two Fiddles in the answer.

Comment: Hi @MrCode when browser recreates, doesn't it reattach the event listeners to every element again? My assumption is that on recreation new listeners get attached that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I quess you do something like that

```
//Place where you add elements.
var container = document.body;
```

you create element and add listener to that element(`button`):

```
var button = '<button id="btn1x">Button 1</button>';
container.innerHTML += button;

//product.id = 'btn1';
document.getElementById(product.id+"x").addEventListener("click", removeItem);
```

and then you add in the same way new elements and add for them event listeners before next element will be generated.

If my quess is right, then your problem is that you replace whole content of `container` so previous event listens are lost.

`stringVariable += 'abc'` is the same as `stringVariable = stringVariable + 'abc'`. Because of that you overwrite html.

You should create elements from functions, not from string as you do now.

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.id = product.id + 'x'; 
button.innerText = 'Button 1'; // Title of button.

//Add button to container.
container.appendChild(button);

//Add event listener to created button.
button.addEventListener('click', myFunc);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

There are a way to parse your string to element.

First create container where will be set inner html from string, then get from that temp container first element (or more elements, depends from your html string), then add them to container and add to these elements listeners.

[DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3cD4G/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/3cD4G/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");

function clicky(){
    alert("clicked");   
}
var tempContainer = document.createElement('div');
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
    //Create your element as string.
    var strElem = "<button type='button' id='btn_" + i + "'>Click</button>";
    //Add that string to temp container (his html will be replaced, not added).
    tempContainer.innerHTML = strElem.trim();//Trim function used to prevent empty textnodes before element.
    //Get element from temp container.
    var button = tempContainer.children[0];
    //Empty tempContainer for better security (But about which security I'm talking in JavaScript in string element generation :) )
    tempContainer.innerHTML = '';

    //Add your button to container.
    container.appendChild(button);

    //Add event listener to button:
    //document.getElementById("btn_" + i).onclick = clicky;
    //Better way to add event listener:
    button.addEventListener('click', clicky);
}
```

[DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3cD4G/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/3cD4G/1/)

Comment: Ohhhhh! okay, thank you for this, I feel this will solve the problem, its just an awful lot of editing to get it to work

Comment: jQuery has a good function ($.parseHTML()), but because you can't use jQuery, you will need to create all elements. But is a good practise, because most html editors has intelli-sense(menu with suggestions) and they will help you write faster and you will be able to find some properties, which you couldn't get using string.

Comment: Is there difference between `el.id=s;` and `el.setAttribute('id', s);`?

Comment: no, there are no difference because HTMLElement objects have such properties. But both ways are correct and native.

Comment: @benharris Answer updated. Found a way to parse your html stirng.